# Is the principal curvature of a cylinder positive or negative according to the second fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

First off, what is the name of the tensor associated with the second fundamental form? For the first fundamental form, I believe we call the associated tensor, "the metric tensor."

Principal curvatures are defined as the eigenvalues of the aforementioned tensor, call it $\bf b$. Well, if we diagonalize $\bf b$ then we obtain ${\bf b} = -\frac{1}{R} {\bf e}_{\theta} \otimes {\bf e}_{\theta}$, where $R$ is the radius of the cylinder, and $\theta$ is defined as usual. This implies that $\kappa_1 = 0$ and $\kappa_2 = -\frac{1}{R}$. But I am pretty sure the nonzero principal curvature of a cylinder is supposed to be positive.

This raises the question: How do we define positive and negative principal curvatures? I have seen definitions about the sum of triangles on the surface having a sum of angles greater or less than $180^o$, but don't find this rigorous. I think it has something to do with how the unit normal changes along the eigenvectors of $\bf b$, no?

We also know that $\frac{d{\bf n}}{ds} = - {\bf b} {\bf t}$, where $\bf t$ is the unit tangent along some curve in the surface and $s$ is the arc length parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[Principal curvatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature) depend on a continuous choice of unit normal field; changing the sign of the unit normal field changes the signs of the principal curvatures. That is, principal curvatures have no intrinsic sign. If you have only a cylinder in Euclidean $3$-space (with no choice of normal field), it makes no sense to say the principal curvatures are non-negative (or are non-positive).

Still assuming you're talking about surfaces in $3$-space, the *product* of the principal curvatures—a.k.a., the [Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature)—does have an intrinsic sign, and indeed, an intrinsic *definition* by the [Theorema Egregium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium). One version of the definition is related to angular defects of triangles, but this is clumsy to make precise.

As for the name of the second fundamental form as a tensor, perhaps you're thinking of the term [*shape operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Shape_operator)?